# Routing issues, can ping core switch but not firewall

Tags: routing, switch, cisco-catalyst

We have a setup with 4 total sites all connected back to one, 2 via fiber and one via a wireless link.  The link with the wireless bridge also needs a vlan (269) from our main site, so we set it up as a trunk instead of a link.

> ```
>                4507-2
>                  ^
>                  |
> WAN -> Sonicwall -> 4507 -> 3560
>                  |
>                  v
>                4507-3
> ```

Cannot ping from 3560 to Sonicwall or external.
Can ping from 3560 to all 4507 switches.
Can ping from Firewall to 3560.

4507 Configuration

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 description *SONICWALL*
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
 spanning-tree portfast

interface GigabitEthernet2/46
 description **Trunk to 3560**
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 269,300
 switchport mode trunk

interface Vlan100
 ip address 10.1.100.1 255.255.252.0
 ip helper-address 10.1.104.10

interface Vlan269
 no ip address
 shutdown

interface Vlan300
 ip address 172.20.20.9 255.255.255.252

ip default-gateway 10.1.100.254
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.1.100.254
ip route 10.4.100.0 255.255.252.0 172.20.20.10
```

3560 Configuration
    ip routing

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/24
 description Trunk to 4507
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 269,300
 switchport mode trunk

interface Vlan100
 ip address 10.4.100.1 255.255.252.0
 ip helper-address 10.1.104.10

interface Vlan300
 ip address 172.20.20.10 255.255.255.252

ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.20.20.9
ip route 10.1.100.0 255.255.252.0 172.20.20.9
```

4507 routes

```
4507#sh ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 10.1.100.254 to network 0.0.0.0

S    192.168.110.0/24 [1/0] via 10.1.104.180
     172.20.0.0/30 is subnetted, 3 subnets
C       172.20.20.8 is directly connected, Vlan300
     10.0.0.0/22 is subnetted, 20 subnets
S       10.4.100.0 [1/0] via 172.20.20.10
C       10.1.100.0 is directly connected, Vlan100
S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 10.1.100.254
```

3560 routes

```
3560#sh ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 172.20.20.9 to network 0.0.0.0

     172.20.0.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.20.20.8 is directly connected, Vlan300
     10.0.0.0/22 is subnetted, 10 subnets
C       10.4.100.0 is directly connected, Vlan100
S       10.1.100.0 [1/0] via 172.20.20.9
S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 172.20.20.9
```

Sonicwall also has a route for 10.4.100.0/22 to go to 10.4.100.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem may be the firewall route.

> Sonicwall also has a route for 10.4.100.0/22 to go to 10.4.100.1

You need the firewall route to go to the next hop, `10.1.100.1`, not to an address on the route itself. You are telling the firewall how to get to that network, and the address of the next hop for the network cannot be on the network itself because the firewall doesn't know how to get to the network where the next hop is, so the firewall cannot send anything to the next hop.

---

My two cents, based on experience:

I would actually have a routed link between the firewall and the layer-3 switch, rather than a VLAN, and run a routing protocol between all the layer-3 devices. Static routes just don't scale.

Configure the switch interfaces as layer-3 interfaces, and address them as point-to-point interfaces with `/30` or `/31` networks. You are using `/30` networks on the SVI for the VLANs, but you can run into some problems with delayed detection of link problems using SVIs, and you don't have that if you address on the physical interfaces.

For the 4507, instead of:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 description *SONICWALL*
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
 spanning-tree portfast
```

Use something like:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 description *SONICWALL*
 no switchport
 ip address 172.20.20.13 255.255.255.252
```

Also, understand that by extending layer-2 VLANs to a remote location, you increase the chances of a layer-2 problem, and the problem will affect two sites instead of one. There is almost nothing today that requires have two hosts on the same layer-2 domain. We live in a layer-3 world, and routing works well. I don't see any advantage to extending the VLAN to a remote location, but I do see some disadvantages to doing it.